# java 8 - store method in HashMap and get return value from method in map

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, functional-interface

I want to store methods pointer in map to execute them based on a string value. Аrom what I found, I can use `Map<String, Runnable>` to do it, but the problem is I want to get the return value from the method.

Say I have something like this:

```
private Map<String, Runnable> timeUnitsMap = new HashMap<String, Runnable>() {{
    timeUnitsMap.put("minutes", () -> config.getMinutesValues());
}}
```

The method `config.getMinutesValues()` is from another class.

How can I do `int value = timeUnitsMap.get("minutes").run();` or to store something else in the map (instead of `Runnable`) in order to get the value from the function in the map?

Comment: Instead of `() -> config.getMinutesValues()`, did you know you can write `config::getMinutesValues`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Runnable` doesn't return a value. You should use `Supplier` or `Callable` instead.

The primary difference between `Supplier` and `Callable` is that `Callable` allows you to throw a checked exception. You then have to handle the possibility of that exception everywhere you use the `Callable`. `Supplier` is probably simpler for your use case.

You would need to change your `Map<String, Runnable>` to a `Map<String, Supplier<Integer>>`. The lambda function itself wouldn't need changing.

@assylias pointed out in a comment that you could also use `Map<String, IntSupplier>`. Using an `IntSupplier` avoids boxing your `int` as an `Integer`.

Comment: Or more likely an `IntSupplier` in this specific case.

Comment: @assylias great idea! That wouldn't have occurred to me.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I do have another question, edited the original one. would appreciate your answer.

Comment: @OfekAgmon please cancel your edit, and ask another, separate question. Your original question has been answered.

Comment: Agreed; one question per post keeps the site organised. Feel free to post another separate question though, I'm happy to take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Callable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) instead of `Runnable`.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use Callable instead of Runnable and also, you would need to override call() method.

You can get a clue from following snippet:

```
private Map<String, Callable<Integer>> timeUnitsMap = new HashMap<String, Callable<Integer>>(){
        {timeUnitsMap.put("minutes", () -> call());}};
```

and you would need to override call() method as well,

```
@Override
    public Integer call() throws Exception {
        return 1;
}
```